# A Poincaré-like inequality

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, inequalities, calculus-of-variations

Is it true that for some real $K>0$ and all real $u\in C_0^\infty((0,1))$ we have
$$\int_0^1 (u'(x)^2+u(x)^2)\,dx\,\int_0^1 u(x)^2\,dx
\le K\Big(\int_0^1 x\,u'(x)^2\,dx\Big)^2\text{ ?}$$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. If $u$ contains a bump of height $1$ and small width $h$, then $\int u'^2\gtrsim 1/h$. On the other hand, this part of $u$ only contributes $\lesssim 1$ to $\int xu'^2$ if we move it close to $x=0$. We can make $\int u^2\simeq 1$ by making $u\simeq 1$ in some other part of the interval, without introducing large derivatives there, so $\int xu'^2$ won't get much larger.

What is true along these lines is $\int u^2\lesssim \int x^2u'^2$; see [the answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451897/caffarelli-kohn-nirenberg-type-inequality-with-nonradial-weight/451959#451959) to [Caffarelli-Kohn-Nirenberg-type inequality with nonradial weight](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451897/caffarelli-kohn-nirenberg-type-inequality-with-nonradial-weight). Incidentally, if you tried to go from here to your inequality, you would need Cauchy–Schwarz in reverse.

Comment: Can you be more explicit how to construct a function with an arbitrarily high K? I'm struggling to see how you can make $\int u^2$ large enough away from 0, without affecting $\int x u'^2$ in $C^{\infty}_0$.

Comment: @Eigentime: $u(x)=x/h$ on $0\le x\le h$, then $u(x)=1$ for $h\le x\le 1/2$, and finally $u(x)=2-2x$ on $1/2\le x\le 1$. This is not in $C_0^{\infty}$, but you can slightly modify it (smooth out the corners, shift it slightly to the right), or observe that the inequality, if it were true for $u\in C_0^{\infty}$, would also hold for this $u$ by approximation.

Comment: now I get it. Thank you.